# Why is the array not displayed in the google sheets table?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have such a custom function that should output a matrix obtained from two arrays.

```
function DOUBLE(range1, range2) {
  var r1Length = range2.length;
  var r2Length = range1.length;

  var tempArr1 = [];
  var tempArr2 = [];

  for (var i = 0; i <= r1Length-1; i++) {
    tempArr1 = tempArr1.concat(range1);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i <= r2Length-1; i++) {
    tempArr2 = tempArr2.concat(range2);
  }

  var matrix = [];
  matrix.push(tempArr1, tempArr2);

  return matrix;
}
```

Arrays are individually shown in google sheets, but if you return the matrix, then for some reason it is not visible in google sheets.

At the same time, if you use this code, the matrix is visible in google sheets:

```
  var student1 = ["Ryan", "Chiu", 3, "Preschool"];
  var student2 = ["Mark", "Sanders", 4, "Pre-K"];
  var student3 = ["Abigail", "White", 3, "Preschool"];
  var student4 = ["Mary", "Lee", 4, "Pre-K"];
  var student5 = ["Rakesh", "Yadav", 5, "Pre-K"];
  var students = [student1, student2, student3, student4, student5];

  return students;
```

If you use the toString() function to the matrix, then it is perfectly visible in google sheet:

Comment: See [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) at MDN.

Answer (score 1):

Custom functions can only return 2D arrays, 1D arrays or single values, while `matrix.push(tempArr1, tempArr2)` will create a 4D array when the function quoted in the question is called with two 2D arrays.

If `tempArr1` and `tempArr2` were 2D arrays, you could make the code work with something like `return tempArr1.concat(tempArr2)`. Problem is that the way the temp arrays are constructed will make these subarrays 3D arrays as well.

In the event you really need to handle 4D or 3D arrays, use [Array.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to diminish the result dimension as needed.